# How to register same type twice with different constructors in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm trying to register the same type but with two different constructors.  When I trying to resolve, I get "*Resolution of the dependency failed*" on the second Resolve.

```
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    container.RegisterType<IBar, Bar>()
        .RegisterInstance(new Bar())
        .RegisterType<IBar, Bar>()
        .RegisterInstance(new Bar("foo"));

    Bar bar1 = (Bar)container.Resolve<IBar>();
    Bar bar2 = (Bar)container.Resolve<IBar>("foo");  // ERROR
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give them names when registering. The parameter to `Resolve` is the name of the instance you want.

```
var container = new UnityContainer();

container
    .RegisterInstance<IBar>("BAR", new Bar())
    .RegisterInstance<IBar>("FOOBAR", new Bar("foo"));

Bar bar1 = (Bar)container.Resolve<IBar>("BAR");
Bar bar2 = (Bar)container.Resolve<IBar>("FOOBAR");
```

Comment: Can you give me an example please.