# How to register repository types with different connection strings

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

**The problem:**

I have two different connection strings:

```
var connStr1 = "Server=...;...";
var connStr2 = "Server=...;...";
```

I have 2 repositories that I want to register with Unity:

```
// I want this repo to use connStr1:
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IRepository1, Repository1>();

// I want this other repo to use connStr2:
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IRepository2, Repository2>();
```

(of course this is a minimal version of the problem, I want N repositories using `connStr1` and M repositories using `connStr2`)

---

**Some necessary info:**

This is how I build a single instance of IDbConnection:

```
var dbConn1 = new CustomDbConnection(connStr1); // returns IDbConnection
var dbConn2 = new CustomDbConnection(connStr2); // returns IDbConnection
```

...and this is how I could build a single instance of each repo:

```
var repository1 = new Repository1(dbConn1);
var repository2 = new Repository1(dbConn2);
```

---

**What I've tried:**

With an injection constructor. This creates a single instance for `dbConn1`, which I want to avoid:

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IRepository1, Repository1>(dbConn1InjectionConstructor);
```

(because I am under the impression that [this kind of registration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/870497/831138) produces a singleton)

This other pattern, but I don't know how to from `connStr1` to `Repository1`:

```
_unityContainer.RegisterType<IDbConnection, CustomDbConnection>("Conn1");
_unityContainer.RegisterType<Repository1>(new InjectionProperty("Conn1"));
```

Comment: Hope I have got you right, if so you are looking out for a concept called [Contextual binding](https://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/08/13/it-depends-part-1-contextual-binding-2/).

Comment: @kayess Thanks for your help. It made sense, but as I poked around I felt it was a bit too complex for me at the moment... so in the end I injected the sql connection string into the repository, and now the repository is in charge of creating a new `IDbConnection` instance for each query. I does it's job, and it's also quite standard to have the connection string at the repository level ( https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Dapper-and-Repository-68710cd7 ).